# How to create Verilog or VHDL from a Quartus design

Tags: fpga, cpu, quartus-ii, alu

I have done a Quartus [design](https://github.com/montao/opencpu) from logical primitives for FPGA. Now I would like to see the corresponding Verilog or VHDL if feasible. Is that possible with Quartus and if so, how?

[image]

Comment: Your "Quartus design" is what specifically? Schematic? Qsys? Sopc builder? etc.

Comment: @TomCarpenter My Quartus design is a 4-bit ALU done with their editor for logical primitives. I include a screenshot and link to the repository.

Comment: Quartus doesn't have an "editor for logical primitives". Your picture is of the schematic editor.

Comment: @TomCarpenter But Qsys can generate VHDL, can't I do it from the schematic editor?

Comment: It only generates the HDL for the processor. I think there might be a way to generate a schematic from HDL, but if you can it looks messy and it wouldn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quartus is indeed capable of generating HDL from a Schematic entry.

With the schematic open, go to:

```
File -> Create/Update -> Create HDL Design File from Current File
```

[image: File->Create/Update Menu]

This will open up a window that allows you to select the desired HDL language:

[image: HDL Language Window]

The resulting HDL file will be placed in the same location as the schematic/block diagram file.

Comment: It works! I got two files: One .v and one .vhd

Comment: @DjDac,They will be horrible VHDL/Verilog files, obfuscated to the point of unmaintainabled. You can use search/replace and careful editing to make it readable. Regularly synthesise it as you go and check that the programmer still gives you the same checksum.